# What is the maximum number of load bearing studs in a row that can be notched?

Tags: plumbing, framing

I'm trying to install a new utility sink and washer hookup in my garage and am trying to plan how I'm going to run the copper supply lines. 
The most direct path I can think of is to notch probably 5 or so studs of an exterior wall to reach the existing drain I'm going to use for the sink.
I know that I can't notch a load bearing 2x4 more than 7/8" but I can't find any guidelines as to how many studs in a row I can safely notch. Is this a question for an engineer? I don't want to go notch crazy but I think 5 or so in a row should be ok? I'm also planning on putting stud shoes on the studs i do notch.

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific limit on the number of sequential studs, as the 7/8" limit is intended to reduce the potential stresses, however, given the choice, I would rather drill than notch:

*2308.9.11 Bored holes. A hole not greater in diameter than 40 percent of the stud width is permitted to be bored in any wood stud. [...]*

and

*In no case shall the edge of the bored hole be nearer than 5/8 inch (15.9 mm) to the edge of the stud.*

So 40% of 3.5 in gives you ~1 3/8" to use, often much more than you need for supply lines.

My concern though, is that you're thinking of notching for a waste line, and notching 7/8" to add a 1 1/2 or 2" drain line is... I'll just say that I'm with @JohnSmith in that I wouldn't bother, but then I don't know your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard question to answer, mainly because there may be local building code that changes the answer depending on the region.  From what I've read, I have not seen any number associated with the maximum number of bearing studs that can be notched. I have seen limitation on boring a hole in the same section as the notch which is not allowed.

WWPA put out [Notching and Boring Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.engineering.com%2Fdownload.aspx%3Ffolder%3D2fda658c-dda7-403f-9165-d97f6092084c%26file%3Dnotch_and_holes.pdf&ei=bjnoUZKdOKWJiALauoD4Bw&usg=AFQjCNFSJm55sFvLxbjn8phyAQNqLwc3Mw&sig2=BU2vt-zjkBpxp87A0DuWPQ&bvm=bv.49478099,d.cGE) which covers some of the common code requirements for notching.  On a bearing wall, you cannot notch more than 25% of the width of the stud, which is as you said, 7/8" max on 2x4 construction. Other areas have similar requirements.

Personally, if its just a hookup in the garage, I don't know that I would notch.  I would probably leave it exposed. (mostly because my garage is pretty rough as it is.)

Answer (score 1):

This varies by code, and with how big your notches are. The safest answer is to limit yourself to 2 consecutive studs. Other codes will say 3 for specific situations. And if the wall isn't load bearing, or you keep the notches small enough, there isn't a limit. The best option is to go through the joists in either the ceiling or floor so that no studs need to be drilled.

References for the 2 stud limit include:
[NAHB](http://www.toolbase.org/ToolbaseResources/level4FAQ.aspx?ContentDetailID=1408&BucketID=1&CategoryID=7) and 
[Dear home insepector](http://activerain.com/blogsview/100877/dear-home-inspector-stud-bore-size).

Here's one from the Florida codes that gives specific limits for their location:

> ```
> 2318.1.9 Notching.
>
> 2318.1.9.1 Studs that carry loads in excess of 75 percent of their 
> capacity shall not be notched or cut.
>
> 2318.1.9.2 Studs that carry loads 75 percent or less of their capacity 
> may be notched to one-third of the depth without limit of the number of 
> consecutive studs.
> ```
>
> [Source](http://publicecodes.cyberregs.com/st/fl/st/b200v07/st_fl_st_b200v07_23_sec013.htm)

Comment: just wanted to note that the NAHB and Dear Home inspector links that reference "2 consecutive studs" are actually a reference to R602.6 in that you can't drill two consecutive *doubled* studs bored between 40-60%. `R602.6 [...] Studs located in exterior walls or bearing partitions drilled over 40 percent and up to 60 percent shall also be doubled with no more than two successive doubled studs bored.` I have yet to find any other limits in the national codes (but would like to know as well).